# GROUP BY in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to do what SQL's GROUP BY does in MATLAB. For example,

M = [
1, 5;
 2, 5; 
3, 5;
 1, 6;
 2, 6;
 1,7 ]

SQL: SELECT MAX(c1), c2 FROM M(c1, c2) GROUP BY 2

Result = [
3, 5;
2, 6;
1, 7]

How can I do this in Matlab?

Comment: I assume octave will have accumarray. Otherwise it should not be hard to get the result by looping over the `unique` values of `M(:,1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grpstats` in the Statistics Toolbox can do this:

```
>> [grpstats(M(:,1), M(:,2), {'max'}) unique(M(:,2))]

ans =

     3     5
     2     6
     1     7
```

Comment: Also, if your data are in a dataset array (also from stats toolbox), the output formatting of `grpstats` is nicer and automatic. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dataset.grpstats.html

Comment: Actually, I am using Octave, which does not have this function. Do you know if I can install it as plugin? Do you know alternative solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind doing some preprocessing to get the order (or if the first column is nicely built from 1 to `n`), you can do it like this:

```
accumarray([1 2 3 1]',[11 12 13 14]',[],@max)
```

This will give:

```
14
12
13
```

Or in your case:

```
accumarray(M(:,1),M(:,2),[],@max)
```

Note the order. The second number for example, will correspond to `M(:,1) == 2`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simple solution to this.
Here is what I tested on Matlab and it worked:

```
>> M = [
1, 5;
2, 5; 
3, 5;
1, 6;
2, 6;
1,7 ];

>> grpstats(M,M(:,2),{'max'})

ans =

     3     5
     2     6
     1     7
```